# Having trouble implementing Apache POI; I have the right dependencies but imports don't seem to work

Tags: apache, spring, apache-poi

I have been trying to implement Apache POI to export Excel files from a Spring 3.0 web app. I tried using many different versions of its dependencies (from 3.2 to 3.8_beta5 version) but it turns out my controller can't recognize the imports in the "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel".

Is there something I am missing? I am very new to this exporting stuff so I am willing to take any suggestions. I would even consider using a completely different API.

Here is the dependency I currently have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

the missing classes are

```
 import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
 import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
 import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
 import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
 import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
 import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
```

Comment: What exactly are the missing classes ?

Comment: They're in that jar; you'll need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a read of the [Overview and Components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html) on the POI website, that tells you which dependencies and/or maven artifacts you need.

If you look there, you'll see that for XSSF, you need to include the *poi-ooxml* artifact as well as the core *poi* one (Maven will then pull down all the other dependencies for you)

Additionally, POI 3.6 is just over 2 years old, and there have been [a lot of bug fixes since then](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html). You'll likely want to use POI 3.8 beta 5, and then upgrade to POI 3.8 final in a few weeks time.

Comment: Thank you for the response but I have tried almost all of the dependencies and tried to import their respective classes. Sorry for the confusion in my post. The thing is I have tried POI 3.8 beta 5 as I have mentioned above.

Comment: I can only suggest that you go and read a maven tutorial then, and learn more about how to use it properly, as what I suggested should work just fine (and does in many projects for me)...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I got it working. I just had to delete all my dependency files and re-download everything from scratch. It finally started working great.